# Classification of real vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am reading Bott and Tu Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology. And I want to prove the classification theorem for isomorphism classes of real vector bundles over $M$, i.e:

> **Theorem 23.12.** Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $m$. There is a
> one-to-one correspondence $$[M,G_k(\mathbb{R}^{k+m})]\cong Vect_{k}(M)$$

Since two results stated for complex vector bundles (Proposition 23.9 and Lemma 23.9.1) also work for real vector bundles (or at least I think they hold), then I only need to proof the following:

> **Theorem (I want to prove).** Given a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and a real vector bundle $E \to M$ of rank $k$. If $n\geq k+m$ and $f,g \colon M \to G_k(\mathbb{R^n})$ are two classifying maps for $E$, then  the maps are homotopic.

In Bott and Tu it is given a reference to Stenrood's book but I had a look at it and I would like to avoid that approach.

**I would love be given a proof of that, some hints, or (preferably and) a reference where I can read it.**

**What I have tried:**
Since the complex case is not proved neither, I have googled for long and I had found one weaker theorem (with two slightly different proofs) which is stated as follows:

> **Theorem (Weaker).** Given a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and a real vector bundle $E \to M$ of rank $k$. If **$n> k+m$** and $f,g \colon M \to G_k(\mathbb{R^n})$ are two classifying maps for $E$, then  the maps are homotopic.

**Note** the strict inequality **n> k+m**.

**Note**: I haven't been able to adapt none of the proofs of the weaker result to the one I want to prove.

I have found that result in [this lecture notes](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Ekoren/DifferentialTopology.pdf) and in Hirsch Differential Topology.

Since I have just started studying vector bundles I would like an *easy*  (as rudimentary as possible) approach (so I can fully understand it). Nevertheless,  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with Steenrod's approach ?

Comment: I am looking for something a bit shorter, a proof which uses less background. That is why I ask. There is nothing wrong with Steenrod approach, I just would like to be aware of other other procedures to prove the statement.

Comment: I don't know any "easy" proof of these statement. The fact that you can find a classifying map is not difficult. It's also not hard to prove that two homotopic maps give the same pulled-back vector bundle. But to show that to classifying maps are homotopic ... you need some hard work.

Comment: I like the treatise in Milnor and Stasheff. You could also have a look at Atiyah's K theory book.

Comment: I found that the weaker result can be used for the purposes I had in mind. Thanks for the references anyway!